# Objective-C MPMediaItem with null URL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, media-player, mpmediaitem

I have a project that makes use of a `MPMediaPickerController` to select audio files from the Media Player. However, when trying to store it's URL, I am getting nothing but `null` returned. My code can be seen below:

```
- (void)showMediaPicker:(NSString *)title {
    MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAny];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.prompt = title;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
    picker.showsCloudItems = NO;
    [self.viewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
    MPMediaItem *item = [mediaItemCollection.items firstObject];
    NSURL *assetURL = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];//returning null
    NSString *type = [self contentTypeForFile:assetURL.lastPathComponent];
    NSString *title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [self callbackWithName:title type:type url:assetURL];
}
```

For whatever reason, my `*assetURL` is nil upon selecting a single audio item from the device's library. The only answers i could find with respect to this problem often relate to the url being `null` when a cloud item is selected from the MediaPicker. However, as seen above, I have set `showCloudItems = NO`.

I would greatly appreciate any help; let me know if you need any additional information!

Comment: What is the value of `item`?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", item) results in:

 <MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x170251a30> 7217559012103102902

Comment: Does `NSURL *assetURL = (NSURL*)[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];` have any effect?

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same result

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, music from the "iCloud Music Library" is DRM protected and therefore, the assetURL is left null when selected in the MPMediaPickerController. The simple fix was to turn off the "iCloud Music Library" setting from within the settings for the "Music" app. I would expect `picker.showsCloudItems = NO;` to prevent this, but apparently I was mistaken.